# Stream Builder Returning Null Value in flutter although Data is present in cloud firestore document

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need help with one case in which my stream builder is returning null values.

I am trying to retrieve a list of services stored in cloud firestore and will display using listview builder later. For now trying to see in the container widget.

I am attaching a snap from my cloud firestore data.

Thanks in Advance.

Here is my code,

```
return Scaffold(
  key: _globalKey,
  body: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 50, right: 20),
    child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore
          .collection('city')
          .doc(Pune)
          .collection(Pashan)
          .doc('merchantData')
          .collection('merchantInfo')
          .where('categoryType', isEqualTo: 'Services')
          .orderBy('storeType', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.data);
        if (snapshot.data != null) {
          _storeTypes.clear();
          for (var num in snapshot.data.docs) {[enter image description here][1]
            if (!_storeTypes.contains(num['storeType'])) {
              _storeTypes.add(
                num['storeType'],
              );
            }
          }
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _storeTypes.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text(_storeTypes[index]),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Just to confirm, `.doc(Pune).collection(Pashan)`. Are those two supposed to be strings or are they declared above as var?

Comment: Those are strings. Sorry I forgot to enclose them in ''. Those are coming from provider package. I replaced the actual value here.
I have verified those value by printing, provider is returning them correctly.

Comment: Similar issue, I have checks for snapshot.hasData yet when I call snapshot.data.data() it returns null. Document definitely exists, I tried with one static id literally copy and pasted from web and returned null...

Answer (score 0):

it's because your trying to use the data before it's fetching from firebase so to avoid the above error add the below code above your if conditions .If you find this answer is correct up vote this answer

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Something went wrong"),
            );
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("No notice found"),
            );
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
```